# Javascript, How to call event listener to not yet created DOM element

Tags: javascript, async-await, async.js

strong textI am trying to add plus and minus to input form.
the input is only created in js script so it doesnt exist on DOM yet when calling the event.

I tried async function but that didn't really work (or i didn't do it right)

this is the function:

```
const plusFunction = async function() {

  function incrementValue(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const fieldName = $(e.target).data('field');
    const parent = $(e.target).closest('div');
    const currentVal = parseInt(parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(), 10);
  
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
      parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal + 1);
    } else {
      parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
    }
  }
  
  function decrementValue(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const fieldName = $(e.target).data('field');
    const parent = $(e.target).closest('div');
    const currentVal = parseInt(parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(), 10);
  
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
      parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal - 1);
    } else {
      parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
    }
  }
  

  const btnPlus = document.querySelector('.button-plus')
  btnPlus.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    
    incrementValue(e);
  });

  const btnMinus = document.querySelector('.button-minus')
  btnMinus.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    decrementValue(e);
  });

}

plusFunction()
```

it is working if the element is already on the html,

any help appreciate.

**edit: I saw some solution with jquery but i need it with vanilla js**

Comment: `How to call event listener to not yet created DOM element` you can't

Comment: @JaromandaX I think the OP means 'attach' instead of 'call'... otherwise you're right, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: you can't attach either - not directly - the element doesn't exist

Comment: so is there any other solution beside using jquery?

Comment: @JaromandaX cant i use promises for that and wait for the load?

Comment: sure, go ahead and do that - what will trigger the Promise fulfilment?

Comment: What's wrong with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements/27373951#27373951) ?